# Аппроксимация функции с помощью функционала scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, математика, numpy, scipy

Пытаюсь аппроксимировать функцию с помощью полинома.

Допустим реальные данные задаются следующей функцией:

```py
# Функция генерирует реальные значения 
def data_gen(x, alpha=1, beta=10, gama=5, per=1.75):
    data = alpha*x + beta*np.sin(per*x) + gama  + x**2 - x**3
    return data
```

Тогда возьмем несколько точек и составим датасет

```py
import numpy as np

# Ось Х
dots = np.linspace(1,8,8)
# Число точек
num_points = len(dots)
# Реальные данные
data = data_gen(dots)
```

Далее напишем функцию полинома, с помощью которого будем аппроксимировать полученные данные.

```py
# Список степеней полинома
set_of_powers = list(range(0, num_points-3))
# Функция аппроксимирующего полинома 
def poly_func_2(w, dots=dots, set_of_powers=set_of_powers):
    features = np.vstack([dots ** i for i in set_of_powers]).transpose()
    power = features.shape[1]
    poly = features @ w.reshape([power,1])
    return poly
```

А также напишем функционал ошибки, который будем минимизировать

```
# Функция минимизации для поиска коэф-ов полинома
def minimize(w, data=data):
    return np.sum((data - poly_func_2(w))**2)/len(data)
```

На выходе получаем веса полинома

```py
# Процесс минимизации
w0 = np.ones(shape=len(set_of_powers))
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=minimize, x0=w0, method='BFGS')

# Итог
w0 = result.x
```

К сожалению, веса подобраны неверно. Ниже приведен график реальных данных, линии полинома, которая получается при подборе параметров с помощью scipy.optimize.minimize, а также линии полинома, которые получается при подоборе параметров с помощью LinearRegression.

[image: Кривые полиномов]

Что мне необходимо изменить в коде или в функционале ошибки, чтобы веса подбирались корректно?

Реализация в коллабе: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UvTor_ewTR877A7d6I20rkx49PifLaCx?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результат вашей функции `poly_func_2` - столбец. Поэтому разность `data - poly_func_2(w)` в `minimize` - квадратная матрица. Сумма всех элементов этой матрицы совсем не похожа на сумму квадратов разностей.

Достаточно, чтобы ваша функция вычисления полинома возвращала строку, а не столбец:

```
def poly_func_2(w, dots=dots, set_of_powers=set_of_powers):
    features = np.vstack([dots ** i for i in set_of_powers]).transpose()
    power = features.shape[1]
    poly = features @ w.reshape([power,1])
    return poly.T
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что хочется улучшить в вашем коде - это то, как вы вычисляете значение полинома.

```
def poly_func_2(w, dots=dots, set_of_powers=set_of_powers):
    return np.polyval(np.flip(w), dots)
```

Это даёт более чем 10% прирост скорости.

Функция `numpy.polyval` предполагает, что коэффициенты идут в порядке от старшей степени к младшей, а у вас наоборот, поэтому перед вычислением полинома нужно поменять порядок на обратный вызовом `numpy.flip`.

А второе, что хочется сделать - заменить вызов `minimize` на `curve_fit` - специализированную функцию аппроксимации.

```
def model(x, *w):
    return np.polyval(w, x)
w, wcov = spo.curve_fit(model, dots, data, p0=np.ones(shape=num_points-3))
w_error = np.sqrt(np.diag(wcov))
```

Функция возвращает оптимальный набор параметров и соответствующую ковариационную матрицу. Квадратный корень из диагональных элементов даёт оценку ошибки аппроксимации (`w_error` в примере).

Вариант с `curve_fit` работает в 40 раз быстрее, чем ваш вариант с `minimize`.